# ServiceTrackerCustomizer service reference returns null

Tags: osgi

I have a persistence bundle containing a Product entity. Since I want to trigger updates on my Solr server on demand, when I'm altering an instance, I introduced an entity listener:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    // id and fields

    @PrePersist
    public void onPersist () {
        ProductAudit.onPersist( this );
    }

    // other lifecycle callbacks
}

public class ProductAudit {
    private static final Set<ProductListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    // static addListener/removeListener

    public void onPersist (Product p) {
        listeners.forEach(l -> {
            l.onPersist(p);
        }
    }
}
```

To integrate my persistence unit into my OSGi environment, I wrote an adapter bundle leveraging a service tracker:

```
@Component(
    name="com.acme.product.audit",
    immediate=true)
public class OsgiProductListener implements ProductListener {
    private ServiceTracker<ProductListener,ProductListener> tracker;

    @Activate
    public void activate (BundleContext context) {
        tracker = new ServiceTracker<>(context, ProductListener.class, new ServiceTrackerCustomizer<ProductListener, ProductListener>() {

            @Override
            public ProductListener addingService(ServiceReference<ProductListener> reference) {
                if (validProps(reference)) {
                    ProductListener l = reference.getBundle().getBundleContext().getService(reference); // null
                    ProductListener l = context.getService(reference); // null too
                    System.out.println("Adding " + l);
                    ProductAudit.addListener(l);
                    return l;
                }

                return null;
            }

            // modifiedService, removedService

            private boolean validProps(ServiceReference<?> reference) {
                // check for enabling flag
            }
        });

        tracker.open();
    }
```

Now I have two provider bundles - a test bundle and an indexer bundle. When I deploy both, on console is printed:

```
 > Activating com.acme.persistence.audit component
  ...
 > Adding com.acme.persistence.test.ProductListenerImpl@1337
 > Adding null
```

All three bundles use the same API version, else my tracker wouldnt track them.

So why I am getting null, if I try to obtain the ProductListener service?

Comment: Squary looking at this question one year later. Since Persistence Units and their mapped classes normally are static, I think it's not the worst case scenario. But today I think a ProductDAO + OSGi event handling would have been a better solution.